# Best Practise For Assigning Serial Number

Tags: sql-server, database, serial-number

I need to assign a number to a document - an RFQ, quote, order, job, etc. The table that will hold this number has a primary key field of type integer, flagged as identity so it will increment automatically. Should I use the value of this field as my serial number, or is it better to have a different field SN of type integer and assign a new record the value max(SN) + 1? Or is there a better way than either of these?

Comment: Well the identity value presents itself as a sequential, self increasing unique integer - is there a reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: Alex K, consider this: I wish to add a record to the table. I have caused the user to fill out all the required information and click a button to add the record. I insert the record using the information provided. Now, how do I return the value of the primary key field for the record I just created? I don't know a way to get back to the new record unless I include a timestamp or some other probably-unique temporary tag, but that seems very iffy.

Comment: `Scope_identity()` returns the last inserted ident value

Comment: That short sentence is a big help to me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have often used something like this.  Assume that the `MyIDValues` table has only one row, so `IDColumn` always holds the most-recently-assigned ID value:

```
DECLARE @NewID Int
UPDATE MyDB.dbo.MyIDValues SET @NewID = IDColumn = IDColumn + 1
SELECT @NewID
```

It simultaneously (i.e. as an atomic statement) updates the table to set the incremented value and returns that value.

In my opinion, this is better than taking the current top value because it always avoids collisions (i.e. if you have software that incorrectly *does* take the top value) by incrementing first and then returning that incremented value.

Comment: I am a little confused about how MyIDValues would have only one row - if I have a table that has a number of records, assuming they each have a valid ID / SN, how would I use this method to assign the next ID / SN? Avoiding collisions is exactly what's on my mind, so we're on the same page there.

Comment: Because the `MyIDValues` table would just hold the ID value that was last handed out.  Why would you need to store all the values that were ever handed out?  The only important piece of information is "what is the last ID value" so you can compute the next one using the code in my example.  Once you obtain the next value, you insert that as the ID value in your table that has all the records and the unique ID requirement.

Comment: So, I have this MyIDValues tablethat has one column IDColumn. It has only one record, and I use your procedure to increment that and return the "new" IDColumn. I then insert my new record into the table using that new value as the serial number. Correct?

Comment: I've seen that approach used in many third-party enterprise applications whose DB schemae I have access to and have worked with.

Comment: Seems very clean, I'm going to run with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash (ie. md5, most languages support this natively) of some idiosyncratic property of the item.

For example, if you have a table of items in a MySQL database, each one probably has an id number that's unique but of no use as a serial number. But a hash will always give you a string of a set length that is also unique, so in php, for example, `$code = md5($id);` (e-mail addresses also work, but  you should [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) anything remotely personal).

The other trick is to carry meaningful data inside a code by stringing together non-sensitive data, like data, time, product item  into "20140101183263-006".

Comment: "But a hash will always give you a string of a set length that is also unique" is not a true statement. Given an output size of sufficient length, you can reduce the odds of collision to be quite small. But guaranteed uniqueness is not a attribute of hashes except in special circumstances.

Comment: It is not inconceivable that such a value would need to be written down, spoken on the phone, *Whats your quote number Mr Smith?"* - *"Its ee81919b049e21ce995decc19dffb6c8"* ...

Comment: @AlexK Fair enough, though the question asks after a general strategy for a wide variety of options, and I offered md5() as one of lots of different options. And there are many strategies for humanizing such things, hyphenated breaks being the obvious one.

Comment: Thanks Jonline, I have never used a hash and I will have to explore the possibility.

Comment: Quite welcome, though if  you're looking at a large-scale project (ie. tens of thousands of generated codes, or codes generated from very large strings) I'd head AlexK's caution.

Comment: @Jonline -- Why wouldn't you just use a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` (i.e. GUID/UUID) then?  You can easily generate one with `NEWID()`.

Comment: TBH I agree with you, on reflection; initially I'd read the question a little hastily and hadn't noticed that the question is specifically generating the codes within the DB. The benefit of a hash is that, provided there is some unique property of the data, it can be generated anywhere and reproduced by anything in  your system that knows how you salt them. So if you need to remotely and/or asynchronously generate your codes and be reasonably sure they're still unique, this is a method that doesn't depend on communicating with the db or otherwise centralizing the service. :)